# change tooltiptext by another tooltiptext on button click event in xul & javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, xul

hi
  I am creating firefox plugin.I have created a button image on toolbar in firefox web browser.I have assigned a tooltiptext="not logged in" to button,but when I click on button,it should show a new tooltiptext="logged in".Please tell me how to change tooltiptext dynamically in xul and javascript.How to change old tooltiptext by another new tooltiptext on button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way is to assign to the element's tooltipText property, but setting the tooltiptext attribute also works.